# How to tell sendmail to send out all mail using Mandrill smtp, smtp port, username, api key?

Tags: centos, email, sendmail, smtp

How to tell my CentOS sendmail to send all the mails of my incoming SMTP using following credentials (which is a third party service, who deliver my mails)?

```
Host smtp.mandrillapp.com
Port 587
SMTP: usernamexyz
SMTP pass: api key
```

Answer (score 0):

Its requires combination of three recipes:

1. Using smart host (e.g. smtp relay) for outgoing email
2. Using non standard TCP port for some outgoing connections
   Sendmail FAQ: 3.39 How do I send using an alternate port?
3. Using authinfo for SMTP AUTH in outgoing SMTP connections

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/sendmail-authentication-for-smart_host-relay-354488/